# Why are random values making pattern?

Tags: r, random, raster

I tried to generate array of zeros and ones, convert to raster and plot it.
I expect to have random pattern, so **why there is apparent pattern in this raster**?
Have I done some mistake in script?

```
# creating vector containing "0" and "1" values...
x<-sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace=TRUE)

# ...converting it into array...
x_arr<-array(x, dim=c(100,100))

# ....nest into raster
x_rast<-raster(x_arr)

# ...and making plot
plot(x_rast)
```

[image]

Comment: You have 1000 elements in x, but you are plotting an array of size 10000. Therefore, x is repeated 10 times, forming a pattern.

Comment: thank you, goddamn zero....  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because 100*100 gives 10000, not 1000, and R will fill up by repeating. Try

```
library(raster)
x<-sample(c(0,1), 10000, replace=TRUE)
```

The example was nice, but please do not forget to paste it into an virgin R before posting. You had forgotten the library.